# Ajax success callback $.each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've never worked with Ajax before and only a little bit with jQuery. Could anyone explain to me what this does? It's from an Atmel embedded webserver example.

```
$.ajax({
     url: "get_chipinfo",
     dataType :'json',
     async: false,
     cache: false,
     success: function(data){
        $.each(data,function(k,v){
            $('#'+k).text(v);
        });
     }
});
```

The confusing part for me here is the `$('#'+k).text(v);`
$('#') is similar to `document.getElementById()`as far as i understood, but what does the `+k` do? Since `k` is the index i would interpret it as selecting #0,#1,#2 and so on, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ajax, `k` stands for `key`, `v` stands for `value`.

Comment: In this example, `$("#" + k)` is the same as `document.getElementById(k)` K is meant to represent a key in a key/value response, where the value is the text for the respective element.

Comment: Please remove `async: false` as it's really bad practice. If you check the console you'll see warnings telling you not to use it. You're already using the callback pattern correctly, so it's not required anyway

Comment: that's just jquery selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k = key
v = value

In the Jquery docs:

If an object is used as the collection, the callback is passed a key-value pair each time:

```js
var obj = {
  "flammable": "inflammable",
  "duh": "no duh"
};
$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key + ": " + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```